# Yii multi database relations

Tags: yii

I have 2 databases.

db1 and db2. I defined them in config/main.php file

db1 has table table1  and db2 has table2

table1 has a column which is primary key of table2

How do I define relations in table1?

I did it as usual but it is retrieving data from db1.table2.

Basically I want to link db1.table1 and db2.table2

Comment: Hi user, if I post my complete code to make this work. Would you give me the tick? Only than I will help ya. :) I solved this already.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Yii Query Builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder), and make a query like this:

```
SELECT u1.* FROM database1.users u1 LEFT JOIN database2.users u2 ON u1.id=u2.id WHERE u2.id IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

To use your another db connection, You can override `getDbConnection()` method in your model. Take a look:

```
public function getDbConnection(){
    Yii::app()->db2->setActive(true);
    return Yii::app()->db2;
}
```

Anyway, Yii 1.X does not officially supports **Cross-Database** relations. You may need to write some codes. As Yii's official **Wiki** says:

> **Limitations on Multi-DB support:**
>   Tables in one database cannot directly reference tables in another database, and this means that relations don't cross DB boundaries.